# Javascript function injected by removed iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

is it possible to inject a javascript function, defined inside an iframe, into the parent window, so that it is available even after the removal of the iframe?
Here is what I do:
in the iframe I have:

```
var f = function(){console.log("iframe function")}
window["iframeFunction"] = f;
```

The parent can successfully call the function until the iframe is available..afterwards it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you define the function in the window's scope and use it in iframe? Or something like including the JS file in home page rather

Comment: You could try to make a copy, in the parent window.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your iframe (ifr.htm)-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function func() {
            window.top.window.f = function() {
                alert('iframe hack');
            }
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            alert('iframe loaded');
            func();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    this is the test iframe.
</body>
</html>
```

and this is your parent window-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            i = document.getElementById('iframe'); //remove the iframe
            i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
            window.f(); //you can still call f() method     
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    this is the parent window.
            <iframe src="ifr.htm" id="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This basically accesses the parent using `top` and adds a function to it. So even when the `iframe` is removed from the DOM, the function will still remain, as it was added to the parent.

Comment: @FrancescoS. How do you remove the iframe in IE?

Comment: var obj = document.getElementById('iframe');
obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);

Comment: @FrancescoS. Updated code. Now it is working fine in IE8. Just make sure to drop out `<!DOCTYPE html>` because IE8 does not support HTML5 Doctype.

Comment: Ok I found an error.. var p = obj.parentNode;     p.removeChild(obj); is better..I have an error because console is undefined..why? anyway with an alert I can see the message after the iframe closure. This however doesn't work if I change the src attribute of the iframe..at least in IE..any idea?? Thanks!!

Comment: @FrancescoS. My bad, IE does not support `console` so change `console.log` to `alert`. If you change `src` attribute after iframe has loaded, it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

[Depending on browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging) requirements, I would recommend [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage). The advantages are:

1. Don't need to pollute parent's global namespace (less chance of collision / availability outside of desired scope)
2. Parent is notified of new function's availability (rather than assuming or polling for change)

**EDIT:** Even if you want to have the function available in the global namespace of the parent with the label specified by the iframe, point 2 still applies.

The code:

```
// In your iframe
var f = function(){console.log("iframe function")}
window.top.postMessage({f:f}, '*');

// In the parent
window.addEventListener('message', function capturePassedFunction(e){
    // If you want to keep this in scope
    var f    = e.data.f;
    // You can still chuck it on the `window` object if you want!
    window.f = e.data.f;
}, false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using IE8/9 and it seems that it doesn't work: addEventListener is not recognized

Comment: Older IEs would use `window.attachEvent("onmessage", function capturePassedFunction(e){…})`. If you're using jQuery, you can just use `$(window).on('message', function capturePassedFunction(e){var f = e.originalEvent.data.f …})`